# What domain name is appended to a default Apple ID when created in OS X?

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id

Upon booting a MacBook Air for the first time (OS X, Version 10.8), I was prompted to create an AppleID. I selected a username and a default domain name was added automatically to this username.

I cannot recall what the domain name was. Does anybody know the default domain name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default domain name for new Apple ID's (or iCloud accounts) is `@icloud.com`. You can also use `@me.com`.